# When I install Entity Framework, the Items don't appear in the Add list (solution explorer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

I'm having problems while installing Entity Framework.

I've tried using NuGet console and the package manager. I've also tried using Visual Studio 2017, but it didn't help. I've also tried multiple other NuGet install commands and that didn't work either.

(no error, just didn't do what I wanted it to do, add EF Items)

But the issue doesn't seem to be installing the package. I have the dependencies in the dependencies folder, under Entity Framework.

It just doesn't show me the EF options when I try to add them to a solution, like models and the such.

relevant pictures:

What I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

What I actually have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the Entity Framework tools installed. The Nuget packages install the relevant libraries for you but they don't modify the IDE.

Close Visual Studio. Then open the Visual Studio Installer from the Start Menu, and click the Modify button.

In the installer, click "Individual Components" and ensure that "Entity Framework 6 tools" is ticked (see image below). Then click the Modify button to install the component.

[image]